# How to write an expressions of the type $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ (function (dot,dot))?

Tags: functions, notation

Assume we have function $f_1:\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y} \to R$ and $f_3:\mathcal{X} \to R$. For any $x,y$, I want to define function $g$ such that $g(x,y) = f_1(x,y) + f_2(x)$. I want to use the dot notation. Is this correct?
$$
g(\cdot,\cdot) = f_1(\cdot,\cdot) + f_2(\cdot)
$$

I think it is not clear what the argument of $f_2$ is. How can we do that? Can we use $\cdot_1,\cdot_2$?

Comment: You could use two different symbols.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Is it correct if I just use $x,y$?

Comment: Introduce $p_1:\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow\mathcal{R}$ defined as $p_1(x,y)=x$ and write $g=f_1+f_2\circ p_1$.